# How to copy "partially" an object using a std::function?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, functor

Here's the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3271314f4bc18ab) I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Test {
    struct Envelope {
        const int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 3;
    };

    Envelope mEnvelope;

    struct Buffer {
        Envelope mEnvelope;
    } mBuffer;
    std::function<Buffer()> func{[this] {
        mBuffer.mEnvelope = mEnvelope;

        return mBuffer;
    }};    
};  

int main() {   
    Test test;
}
```

it says:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:17:29: error: use of deleted function 'Test::Envelope& Test::Envelope::operator=(const Test::Envelope&)'
   17 |         mBuffer.mEnvelope = mEnvelope;
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:12: note: 'Test::Envelope& Test::Envelope::operator=(const Test::Envelope&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    5 |     struct Envelope {
      |            ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:12: error: non-static const member 'const int Test::Envelope::x', can't use default assignment operator
```

I've tried using a Copy Constructor:

```
Envelope(const Envelope &other) {
    y = other.y;
}
```

or override the operator `=`

```
Envelope &operator=(Envelope &other) {
    // self-assignment guard
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }            

    y = other.y;
}
```

But the errors grown even more.

I need to copy only some "part" of the object.
This is just a test, of course the real object have lots of members fields, and some need to be ignored.

How to do it within a `std::function<Buffer()>`?

Comment: Following the *non-static const member* in the error message, have you considered making the member `static`?

Comment: @walnut if I write as you said, it says `implicitly-declared` is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]

Comment: @markzzz not if you define both

Comment: @walnut right! Seems to works perfectly! If you reply, you give "accepted". Thanks

Comment: @walnut but it seems I need to write the same code on both copy ctor and operator =? Can be declared only once?

Comment: Your `operator=` isn't returning anything if `this != &other`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since it might not be obvious what the problem is:

1. A copy assignment operator should usually have a `const&` parameter, not a `&` parameter.
2. You should then also provide the copy constructor of `Envelope` as you showed. First of all it has different behavior than the implicitly-generated one (which would copy over all the elements, not only `y`) and the generation of the implicit copy constructor when there is a user-defined copy assignment has been deprecated since C++11 and will probably be removed in a future standard iteration.
3. Then you will need to default the default constructor as well, since you have a user-defined constructor now:

   ```
   Envelope() = default;
   ```
4. Furthermore, your copy assignment operator is declared to return a `Envelope&` (as it should), but you forgot to actually put a return statement in it at its end, so executing it will cause undefined behavior as is:

   ```
   return *this;
   ```

Comment: But do I need both operator `=` and copy ctor? that's what I don't understand

Comment: @markzzz This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom and as I mentioned the copy constructor is not stictly required (yet), but you will need to implement it if you want the specific semantics that only `y` is copied and the other two members are defaulted.

Comment: check this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a8742f179b0baad . It seems that I need to copy the data on both operator and copy ctor for work (remove the comment on `//y = other.y; // THIS SEEMS NEEDED`). The fact is: if I copy 20 variables, I need to copy 20 + 20 on both copy ctor and operator. Is that normal?

Comment: @markzzz Yes, obviously you must make the copy constructor actually copy the parts that you want to copy. I assumed that you explicitly do not want to copy certain parts. If you just want the copy constructor to copy all members, you can default it explicitly: `Envelope(const Envelope&) = default;`. The copy assignment must be specified in full, defaulting it will not be enough.

Comment: General side note: If `x` is supposed to *always* be `1` without a way of initializing it to something else, then you could simply make it `static`, so that you won't need to define any of the special member functions yourself.

Comment: @markzzz Yes, that is normal. And because that are too many to do manually, I usually factor those where the defaulted copy constructor/assignment is sufficient into a helper `struct` that is then used as base class in the actual class.

Comment: I just want to copy some prevent to copy all data, which I don't need and code must be faster. Not clear why it used both operator and Copy ctor. Shouldn't It use one or the other?

Comment: Ok, got it why: i use both because I do two different copy. I'll try to review my code, to do it once...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own copy ctor/operator in order to only copy the info you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Test {
    typedef struct  {
        const int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    } Envelope_t;

  public:
    Test():env({1,2,3}){}

    Test(const Test & copy):env({copy.env.x,5,copy.env.z}) {}

    Test& operator=(const Test& copy){   
      env.y=copy.env.y+7;
      env.z=copy.env.z;
      return *this;
    }

    void printValues() {
        std::cout << "x:" << env.x << "\ny:" << 
                     env.y << "\nz:" <<  env.z << "\n\n";
    }

  private:
    Envelope_t env;
};  

int main() {   
  Test original;
  original.printValues();

  Test copyCtor(original);
  copyCtor.printValues();

  Test copyOp;
  copyOp = copyCtor;
  copyOp.printValues();
}
```